# Upwork developed Flutter App into Play Store and Iphone Apps Store

Tags: flutter, google-play, app-store

I commissioned a dev on upwork to build my app for me and release it into play store and app store, the agreenent was that I own the code but the dev has been using his own signing keys,etc.

Do I need to create my own signing keys to put into the code? Or do I need to be doing this myself?

Should I create my own Play account? Can I get my dev to release it into my play account?

What else do I need to replace to make it mine so I dont have to rely on that dev to make changes down the road?

Anything else I should worry about?

Comment: Create your own Play Store account and create your own signing key that way you don't have to use your developers key and account name. If you want to make changes to the code later on you would have to upload it through your account.

Comment: any harm in giving the dev my signing key? or should I always be compiling my own APK in the end before putting it into Play Store?

Comment: If you know how to upload an android app I would do it yourself. If your developer is going to to be handling all the future updates then I would keep the account and keys with him for simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

In order to be owner of your own code and be completely independent for future releases with another developer you would need the following:

1. Your own account on the App Store / Play Store, so you can manage developer's access when they do the release of the app, but you keep the account and full admin access and they can't temper with the app itself once released.
2. Git (github, gitlab, bitbucket or any 3rd party provider) account and repository to which you give access for the developer, so he can commit code of the app. This preserves the history of his work + you can manage multiple people having access on the same codebase. Also already pushed code can't be lost on his local PC.

Other than that all accounts that are needed for 3rd party services also need to be created by your own account. An example would be Firebase console account or google account to access it's API for geolocation or any other 3rd party...

Regarding keys...all keys that are generated during the development time serve for that development period, and they can be changed later on when new developer comes onboard. The developer can share them with you, so you too have access to it all, but that's not something that can block your action on the account/application at any point when you break up the contract for any reason.

Answer (score 0):

You should own your apple and google store account and signing key for every app released on the stores.
Of course you have to own the code but if you want to publish your app the code needs to be built and get signing and be uploaded on the stores.
You could make your developer in charge in building, uploading and getting feedback from apple or goolge store team or customers
The signing key do nothing changes in your code. it will be used only when build your app and devlier to the stores and somewhere else.